# Can graphene resolver return Float instead of String for django Decimal field?

Tags: django, django-models, type-conversion, graphene-python, graphene-django

Graphene's resolver returns my django model Decimal field as a string (e.g. "8.33" instead of 8.33).  I want to receive it as a float.  Is there some way to do this?

My code is as follows:

**models.py**

```
class Toy(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.DecimalField()
```

**queries.py**

```
class ToyType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Toy
        fields = ('name', 'price')

class ToyQuery(graphene.ObjectType):
    first_toy = graphene.Field(ToyType)
 
    def resolve_first_toy(self, info):
        return Toy.objects.first()
```

And my query and result are:

**query**

```
{
    firstToy{
        name
        price
    }
}
```

**result**

```
{
    "data": {
         "name": "BuzzLighYear",
         "price": "19.95"

     } 
}
```

**Instead, I would like to receive:**

```
{
    "data": {
         "name": "BuzzLighYear",
         "price": 19.95

     } 
}
```

Do I have to write a custom resolver for the price field, or is there a more elegant way to do this with a setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out you do not have to write a customer resolver, but instead can just declare the type of the Django field, like so:

```
class ToyType(DjangoObjectType):

    price = graphene.Float()

    class Meta:
        model = Toy
        fields = ('name', 'price')
```

In this way, the resolver will return price as a Float.  If you do not explicitly declare the type, the graphene default is to return the django Decimal field as a string.

Answer (score 0):

To convert the decimal value to a float, use a custom resolver as shown.

```
class ToyType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Toy
        fields = ('name', 'price')

    price = graphene.Float()

    def resolve_price(self, info):
        return float(self.price)
```

[Sample query and response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRKSL.png)